# How to make top/bottom borders appear ontop of left/right borders crossbrowser css

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser, border

I want to style a table spreadsheet like, with vertical grey borders, and horizontal black borders (for sums).

I get what I want in chrome with this: https://jsfiddle.net/m9abo8f6/4/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr><td>row1</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>row2</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>row3</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total</td><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color:white;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

tr:last-child {
  border-top: 1px double black;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

But IE (11) renders the vertical borders on top of the horizontal, also the horizontal border isn't quite black in IE, so there is something more going on there.

Is there a way to get what I want (chrome's render of the above) in css, without tricks like overlaying divs/other elements, reasonably cross browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color:white;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

tr:last-child td:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: -2px;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>row1</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row2</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row3</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Total</td><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```